# IS it possible to use fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate the following derivative?

Tags: calculus

Suppose

$$ G(x) = \int\limits_{\sin x}^{\cos x} \frac{ \sin ( \tau^2 + 1) }{\arcsin \tau } d\tau $$

to evaluate $G'(x)$, shouldnt we just break this integral in two and then use the chain rule?? Is there another way to compute the derivative?

Comment: What is $F'(x)$?

Comment: Assuming you mean $G'(x)$, this is basically a chain rule problem: you have $G(a,b)=\int_a^b g(t) dt$, then you want $\frac{d}{dx} G(\sin(x),\cos(x))$. So you get $\frac{\partial G}{\partial a} \frac{d(\sin(x))}{dx} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial b} \frac{d(\cos(x))}{dx}$. But $G(a,b)=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F$ is some antiderivative, so you can use the FTC to get the partials.

Comment: What is you write $G = \int_{\sin x}^a g( \tau) + \int_a^{\cos x} g (\tau) $ and then use FTC to evaluate each of them using chain rule.

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy That's an equivalent approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$G(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt$$ the fundamental theorem of calculus gives $$G'(x))=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x)) \,a'(x)$$ So, there is no need to break the integral.

Just applying to the case where $$f(t)=\frac{ \sin ( t^2 + 1) }{\arcsin(t)} \qquad a(x)=\sin(x)\qquad b(x)=\cos(x)$$ $$G'(x)=-\frac{\sin (x) \sin \left(\cos ^2(x)+1\right)}{\sin ^{-1}(\cos (x))}-\frac{\cos (x)\sin
   \left(\sin ^2(x)+1\right)}{\sin ^{-1}(\sin (x))}$$